# Inno Setup - Give only 'Cancel' option on "Preparing to Install" page, if application is running

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to edit this window and give the user only *'Cancel'* option?  When the setup finds that the application is running and using one of the files in the setup, I want to give the user only *'Cancel'* option to exit the setup.

I'm using Inno Setup 5.5.9

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the "Preparing to Install" page:

- Hide the two radio buttons
- Disable the *Next* button
- Reword the `ApplicationsFound2` message

```
[Messages]
ApplicationsFound2=The following applications are using files that need to be updated by Setup. Please close them.
```

```pascal
[Code]

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpPreparing then
  begin
    WizardForm.PreparingYesRadio.Visible := False;
    WizardForm.PreparingNoRadio.Visible := False;
    WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := False;
  end;
end;
```

[image: Preparing to Install]

---

Though, if your need to prevent the installer from running, when the application is running, a more appropriate solution is to use the [`AppMutex` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appmutex).

Comment: Thank you! exactly what i was looking for